# To display secondary views under Eclipse menu Window -> Show VIew

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin

I have created a Eclipse plugin application, in which there are many secondary views created at runtime for a single static view. In the menu `Window-> Show View`, only the entry for the view statically created in the `plugin.xml` is displayed.

But the view that is created statically is useless in terms of showing results because the results are shown dynamically at runtime in the secondary views.

So, I want to display those secondary view in the menu `Window->Show VIew` and remove the entry for that static view from there.

Is it possible to do the same?
If yes, any suggestion in this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I believe [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg12476.html), the surest way to have a fine control over the content of the 'Window > Show View' menu is to build one...

I.e. Creating your own version of shortlist view menu item, with a code similar to [`org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowViewMenu`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/ShowViewMenu.java.htm)

Comment: Dear VonC,

Thank you for your reply.
I'd gone through that thread and source code you referred. But I think the function ShowViewMenu() doesn't support any parameters like secondary view id. So, I am not sure it's feasible to do so that way. Also addShowViewShortcut() function doesn't support parameter for secondary id.
For information of other users with similar problem, please refer below:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294066

Answer (score 0):

iThe secondary view is not designed to be used like that. Secondary views are views that are created programmatically and the list you mention is build from the extension points.

If you want to list all active views you should make your own menu and add that to Eclipse.

To get the list of views you use

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IViewReference[] viewReferences = page.getViewReferences();
viewReferences[i].getId();
viewReferences[i].getSecondaryId();
```